Django Update on UniqueConstraint
I'm trying to work with UniqueConstraint but I've been facing some issues trying to update it the way I want.
I have the following model
class QueryModel(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(_("query id"), primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(_("query name"), max_length=150)
    status = models.CharField(
        _("query status"),
        choices=QueryStatus.choices,
        default=QueryStatus.ACTIVE,
    )
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(_("favorite"), default=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(_("date created"), auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta(object):
        app_label = "app"
        db_table = "query"
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=("user",),
                condition=Q(is_favorite=True),
                name="unique_favorite_per_user",
            )
        ]

class QueryView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    View to list all users in the system.

    * Requires token authentication.
    * Only admin users are able to access this view.
    """

    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = QuerySerializer
    aws_client = AWSClient()

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the purchases
        for the currently authenticated user.
        """
        self._paginator = None
        return QueryModel.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by("id")

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = QuerySerializer(
            data={
                "user": request.user.id,
                "name": request.data["name"],
                "expiration_date": request.data["expiration_date"],
                "json": request.data["json"],
            }
        )

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        serializer = QuerySerializer(data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        if "is_favorite" in serializer.validated_data.keys():
            self.get_queryset().update(
                is_favorite=ExpressionWrapper(Q(pk=pk), BooleanField())
            )

        return super().partial_update(request, pk)

router = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register("auth", AuthView, basename="auth")
router.register("query", QueryView, basename="query")

version_info = json.load(open("./version.json"))


@api_view(["GET"])
def health_check(request):
    """Check if the endpoint is on. Used by container orchestration system."""
    return Response({"status": "pass", **version_info})


urlpatterns = [
    path("", health_check),
    *router.urls,
]

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 105, in _execute
     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_favorite_per_user"
 DETAIL:  Key (user_workspace_id)=(2) already exists.
 
 
 The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
     response = get_response(request)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 65, in _view_wrapper
     return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 124, in view
     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
     raise exc
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/var/lib/trends_backend/trends/views/query.py", line 61, in partial_update
     self.get_queryset().update(
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1253, in update
     rows = query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1990, in execute_sql
     cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1562, in execute_sql
     cursor.execute(sql, params)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 122, in execute
     return super().execute(sql, params)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
     return self._execute_with_wrappers(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 92, in _execute_with_wrappers
     return executor(sql, params, many, context)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in _execute
     with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 105, in _execute
     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_favorite_per_user"
 DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(2) already exists.

So in my system, users can create queries and set them as favorites, but each user can only have 1 favorite query, so I created the UniqueConstraint to enforce that business rule.
Then I would have an endpoint to set a query as favorite, but is there a way for me to update that field without having to check all is_favorite fields of each user and manually setting them to False?
I found this StackOverflow post from 2 years ago that proposes a solution, but this solution is not working for me, I would really appreciate some help

If you want to set the QueryModel with my_pk as primary key as favorite, you update with:
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q

QueryModel.objects.filter(user=my_user).update(
    is_favorite=ExpressionWrapper(Q(pk=my_pk), BooleanField())
)
This will automatically disable a favorite if there is already one, and set it to the one with my_pk as primary key.
Alternatively, we can work with two updates, one to set all rows to False, and then one to set one to True:
QueryModel.objects.filter(user=my_user).update(is_favorite=False)
QueryModel.objects.filter(user=my_user, pk=my_pk).update(is_favorite=True)

Actually, at first it worked, and then I kept getting
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_favorite_per_user"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(2) already exists.

It sometimes works and sometimes doesn't I don't know why

@PedroDaumas: but when? When you create an item with the favorite=True, because that can indeed happen, you better first save it with is_favorite set to False, and then run the update query.

items are usually created with is_favorite as False, my test consist of running the patch endpoint that has the code multiple times for multiple different queries, so:
run: localhost/query/1 to set it as favorite then localhost/query/2 and so on, I only have 3 queries in my test.
After a couple of iterations I start getting this error message

Can you edit the question with the view, url, etc.?

Sorry, I updated the question!

This error seems to occur when a item moves to True, then False and then True again

So you make three PATCH requests?

yes, I'm trying to simulate a user changing the favorite query multiple times, since I have 2 queries in my tests, I run it 3-4 times changing which one is the favorite every time

And the error happens at the .update(..)? (the traceback of the exception point to that)?

Yes, I added the traceback to the question

@PedroDaumas: are you sure you are not filtering somehow (for example by a custom manager)? What does print(self.get_queryset().query) shows? The update should span all records for that user, so not only "active" ones (for example through a soft delete).

I'm filtering by user, just like the one in your post, my query set for this view is just a simple filter by user. The print returns
SELECT "query"."id", "query"."user_id", "query"."name", "query"."status", "query"."is_favorite", "query"."date_created" FROM "query" WHERE "query"."user_id" = 2 ORDER BY "query"."id" ASC

Hmm, very strange. It almost looks as if the update is not done atomically, but that the database does it one row at a time.

@PedroDaumas: what if you use the second approach? See edit. But it is rather bizarre, normally one expects that an update works atomically, here it looks as if the database does this in a row-by-row manner.

Yes, I have used the second approach before and it does work. I was trying to look for a solution without having to set everything as false.
I'm using a docker Postgres so I don't know if that has anything to do with this issue

@PedroDaumas: normally no. Perhaps it is a setting in PostgreSQL how an update is handled. Normally the idea is that the database checks after the complete UPDATE, so not row-by-row, since then it can of course happen that we set the first row to True, and the second one, we still have to update is still False, but it would be bizarre if the database checks/updates it that way. So this might be some setting.

yea, this seems to be something related to the UniqueConstraint, if I remove the constraint the query works without returning any errors.

@PedroDaumas: well, can you inspect the database, especially the constraint. Normally it is or the constraint that is not translated correctly, or the database that is set to update in a way that thus does not really work well with that contraint.
